# Ubuntu kernel downgrade to 5.19.0-32 failed (no installation candidates)

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I am trying to downgrade my Ubuntu 22.04 kernel from 6.2.0-26-generic to 5.19.0-32-generic, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480283/ubuntu-kernel-upgrade-to-6-2-0-26-failed/1481608#1481608) because I have the same issue (black screen while booting).

When I execute `apt install linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic` from recovery mode, as I cannot boot my Ubuntu in graphic mode, I get the *has no installation candidate* error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Do `apt policy linux-image-5.1*` to find all installation candidates starting with the string `linux-image-5.`, then see if you can install any.

Comment: @Jos I have installed 5.19.0-41, 5.19.0-45 and some more, but they don't solve my problem. That's why I need to install that specific kernel, since in the mentioned question is the one that worked for other people.